# How to handle jQuery POST data to apache shown as GET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache, post, get

I'm trying to POST data to apache webserver/API throught a json ajax jQuery.
I tried both:

```
$.ajax({type: "post", {name:val} ... ... });
```

and

```
$.post({{name:val}... ... });
```

On the Firebug output, I got: "POST" calls, looks fine.

But on the Apache side, I got "GET" calls (on the log access files)

How do I manage post with jquery?

Thanks.

Comment: Apache is on server-side, it's normal to be like that, isn't it??

Answer (score 0):

well at first glance it's a simple problem. You are not specifying a url to route your data to. 
unless the ......... means that there is more to your ajax calls. Please provide code if so. otherwise, here is a lnk to the ajax api. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

typical example would look like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "path/to/your/script/on/the/server.fileExtention",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + data );
});
```